# How can i install mythtv 0.24 on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mythtv, versions, xbmc

I am trying to figure out the easy way to install mythtv 0.24 on ubuntu 12.04.

I want to use xbmc as front end and mythtv 0.25

It will not work right?

Answer (score 3):

**For Ubuntu precise (12.04), raring (13.04), saucy (13.10), trusty (14.04) use version 0.27:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.27
```

**For Ubuntu precise (12.04), quantal (12.10), raring (13.04) and version 0.26:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.26
```

**For Ubuntu lucid (10.04), natty (11.04), oneiric (11.10), precise (12.04), quantal (12.10) and version 0.25:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.25
```

**For Ubuntu lucid (10.04), maverick (10.10), natty (11.04), oneiric(11.10) and version 0.24:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.24
```

After adding *one* of these repositories, you can update and install with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mythtv
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to install MythTV 0.24 on Ubuntu 12.04. The version in 12.04 is 0.25, so you have two options.

1) Attempt enabling the 0.24 repository for a previous Ubuntu release, force that version to install, then lock/pin it. You should use one of the PPAs listed here.

https://launchpad.net/~mythbuntu/+archive/0.24

2) Compile MythTV 0.24 from source.